# Having issues with rs.add() in ansible playbook for mongo

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I am using below tasks in my playbook to initialize cluster and add secondary to primary:

```
- name: Initialize replica set
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: host1
  shell: >
       mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.initiate())'

- name: Format secondaries
  run_once: true
  local_action:
     module: debug
     msg: '"{{ item }}:27017"'
  with_items: ['host2', 'host3']
  register: secondaries

- name: Add secondaries
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: host1
  shell: >
        /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add({{ item.msg }}))'
  with_items: secondaries.results
```

I am getting below error:

```
TASK [mongodb-setup : Add secondaries] *******************************
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'msg'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_dev/roles/mongodb-setup/tasks/users.yml': line 15, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add secondaries\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Thanks for the response, I have amended my code as below

```
-  name: Add secondaries
   run_once: true
   delegate_to: host-1
   shell: >
        /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add({{ item }}:27017))'
   with_items:
    - host2
    - host3
```

but getting below error

`failed: [host-2 -> host-1] (item=host-2) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add(host-2:27017))'", "delta": "0:00:00.173077", "end": "2019-08-06 13:29:09.422560", "item": "host-2", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 252, "start": "2019-08-06 13:29:09.249483", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22\nconnecting to: test\n2019-08-06T13:29:09.419-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell eval):1:37", "stdout_lines": ["MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22", "connecting to: test", "2019-08-06T13:29:09.419-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell eval):1:37"]}`

Comment: Did you try to run the command manually ? Don't you simply need to quote your argument somehow ?

Comment: Yes, put it in quotes, still it failed ```shell: "/usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add({{ item }}:27017))'"```

Comment: By quoting argument, I meant (with a pure guess) the one to `rs.add`. I just searched and it looks like it is [effectively expecting a string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/). See my edited answer below

Comment: @Zeitounator . Thanks for all your help, but still I am facing below error, tried lot of combinations```Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  did not find expected key\n\ shell: \"/usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add(\"{{ item }}\\:27017\"))'\"\n```

Comment: Did you try exactly as in my answer? What you are describing here is a basic y'all error probably because of a quoting issue. And also: did you check that your command is running ok when you laugh or manually in a shell on your server?

Comment: Issue is resolved now after I removed double-quotes after shell : "" . Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197620/discussion-between-user312307-and-zeitounator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is not with `rs.add()` but with the data you loop over. In your last task, your item list is a single string.

```
# Wrong #
with_items: secondaries.results
```

You want to pass an actual list form your previously registered result:

```
with_items: "{{ secondaries.results }}"
```

That being said, registering the result of a debug task is rather odd. You should use `set_fact` to register what you need in a var, or better directly loop other your list of hosts in your task. It also looks like the [`rs.add` funcion is exepecting a string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) so you should quote the argument in your eval. Something like:

```
- name: Add secondaries
  shell: >
    /usr/bin/mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.add("{{ item }}:27017"))'
  with_items:
    - host2
    - host3
```

And the way you use delegation seems rather strange to me in this context but it's hard to give any valid clues without a complete playbook example of what you are trying to do (that you might give in a new question if necessary).